# How to get rid of rats in house with/without killing it

Tags: home, pest-control

There is small rat in my house I want to get rid of. I have kept poison and rat bone but nothing happened. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are humane traps such as [Havahart](http://www.havahart.com/store/animal-traps/rats). Peanut butter is *very* attractive for rodents. BTW, I have stayed in a national park which had a mouse problem in cabins... When I went to bed, a humane trap had gotten one critter, so I left a pencil for it to nibble, rather than the hard wire cage. In the morning, it had two more buddies awaiting a trip into the woods.

Comment: I've had mice return to my house after bringing them nearly a mile away.  Yes, I am sure it was the same mouse, I had a suspicion and took pictures of it before the release.

Comment: @drmoishe will surely try your suggestion today and let you know